# Get discussion web part to display posts

Tags: web-part, discussion-board

I'm using a default SharePoint 2010 discussions web part in my site. By default it displays the top level posts that have been made to the discussion. When I click on a discussion it takes me away from the page hosting the web part and back to the standard discussion view page.

Is there a way I can get the posts for a single discussion thread displayed in the web part rather than having to navigate away to another page thus breaking my site's look and feel?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that the OOB discussion web part can display the posts as well. You would need to use the SharePoint Object Model and code you own one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm speaking from experience in MOSS but I don't think SP2010 is any different.

Yes - discussion lists work off of a folder structure: discussion posts are folders and responses are items in those folders. You can escape the responses in a LFWP just by adjusting the view to show items outside of folders. You can escape the responses in a DVWP by adjusting the data source item and scope properties.

To make this appear sensible, you might find it easiest to do two Web parts on the page: one for discussions up top and one for replies below and make a Web Part Connection between the two where Subject (of Discussion Post) = Discussion Title (of Reply). Use the "trimmed body" column in the Replies DVWP to keep it clean.